# Using Tika for mime type detection gives unexpected results

Tags: apache, apache-tika

I am using Tika for detecting  mime type by using this code

```
InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();
Tika tika = new Tika();
String mediaType= tika.detect(inputStream);
```

Now when I am uploading a doc file it is detecting it's mediatype as **application/xhtml+xml**, Although it should have detect it as **application/msword**, This is happening with some doc file only not all of them

Comment: Are they perhaps `.html` files which someone has renamed the extension of? If you rename them back to `.html` from `.doc`, do they open fine in a web browser?

Comment: @Gagravarr- They are behaving the same way the other doc file behaves in browser.

Comment: Can you open a bug in the Apache Tika JIRA bug tracker, and upload one of the problematic files?